# How do I edit my database so I can link it with my models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I have already created a model that processes user names and password , but no database.  How can I go backwards (without using scaffold) and essentially say "put all these users and passowords into a table with an auto_increment ID field" to the database.

This is probably a very easy task, but I am so new to rails and how everything interacts that I'm having a tough time with it.

Comment: Really this is pretty much the first thing you would read in any of the gazillions of rails tutorials on the web. :)

Answer (score 1):

Start here: [Rails Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

We'll need a few details before we can provide any more specific help.